# Cloning my Hard drive.

Tags: installation, hard-drive, mac, cloning, user-data

2 weeks ago I installed ubuntu and after my back-up hard drive failing I moved all my data onto the hard drive too. I have a Mac laptop and now my replacement hard drive has arrived. I was wondering if it were possible to connect my mac to the old hard and transfer data (install,settings and all) to the new one.

Is this possible?

It would be really good if it was just a simple cloning process as I have my desktop, application and settings all running correctly.

Comment: Is it a desktop or a laptop? If it is a desktop it should be easy. Just plug the HDD into a new SATA port and clone using [clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/). A laptop is harder because you can't have both plugged in at once.

Answer (score 0):

Use Clonezilla on a USB to duplicate local HDD to the new one.

1. Create and boot Clonezilla on a laptop/desktop with backup HDD inside
2. After booting, plugin new HDD with a USB adapter
3. Clone local HDD to USB HDD
4. Replace local HDD with new one and boot the system